# NestJS ClientRedis emits but EventPattern handler not triggered

Tags: typescript, redis, nestjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running @nestjs 7.6.18.  I'm following the instructions on [how to wire up Redis](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/redis) to emit and receive events.  I've attached the smallest reproduction so you can run it for yourself.  Here is the setup:

#### main.ts

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await NestFactory.createMicroservice<RedisOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: { url: 'redis://localhost:6379' },
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

#### AppModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TransportModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### AppController

```js
  @EventPattern(EVENT_NAME) // <- EVENT_NAME is string constant 'EVENT_NAME'
  onEvent(data: any) {
    Logger.log('Event received'); // <- this is never executed
    Logger.log(data);
  }
```

#### TransportModule

```js
export const EVENT_NAME = 'EVENT_NAME';
export const NEST_REDIS = Symbol('NEST_REDIS');

export const RedisProvider: Provider = {
  provide: NEST_REDIS,
  useFactory: () =>
    ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.REDIS,
      options: { url: 'redis://localhost:6379' },
    }),
};

@Module({ providers: [RedisProvider] })
export class TransportModule implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  constructor(@Inject(NEST_REDIS) private client: ClientRedis) {}

  onApplicationBootstrap() {
    this.client.connect().then(() => {
      Logger.log('REDIS is connected');
      this.startEmitting();
    });
  }

  startEmitting() {
    let msgNumber = 0;

    // wait 3 secs, then start emitting every 8
    timer(3000, 8000)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => Logger.log(`Emitting message #${++msgNumber}`)),
        tap(() => this.client.emit(EVENT_NAME, { messageNumber: msgNumber })),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

When I run this, the messages are emitted properly, but the `AppController.onEvent` handler is never triggered

My Redis is `6.2.4`, running from a Linux shell on Windows.  The application is running on Windows proper.  This is the application log:

[image]

This is what I see in `redis-cli` when I subscribe to the stream.  I think the cli is the only subscriber (i.e. NestJS is not listening on the channel) because the integer 1 is returned:

[image]

And here is the repo, if you wish to run it (`npm run install` then `npm run start`)
[Source code](https://send.bitwarden.com/#80wtWmbUHES9qK1dAA7WNQ/0Ofmar46Ga4O2LXhuHHMjg)

Answer (score 1):

NestJS was not listening on the Redis channel because after creating the microservice, I never started it.  In `main.ts` I had to change:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await NestFactory.createMicroservice<RedisOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: { url: 'redis://localhost:6379' },
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

To:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  redisMicroservice = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<RedisOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: { url: 'redis://localhost:6379' },
  });

  redisMicroservice.listenAsync(); // <- new line
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```